# gRPC client reconnect inside Kubernetes

Tags: grpc

If we define our microservice inside Kubernetes pods, do we need to instrument a gRPC client reconnection if the service pod is restarting?

When the pod restarts the host name is not changed, but we cannot guarantee the IP address remains the same. So is the gRPC client still be able to detect the new server to reconnect to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the TCP connection is disconnected (because the old pod stopped) gRPC's channel will attempt to reconnect with exponential backoff. Each reconnect attempt implies resolving the DNS address, although it may not detect the new address immediately because of the TTL (time-to-live) of the old DNS entry. Also, I believe some implementations resolve the address when a failure is detected instead of before an attempt.

This process happens naturally without your application doing anything, although it may experience RPC failures until the connection is re-established. Enabling "wait for ready" on an RPC would reduce the chances the RPC fails during this period of transition, although such an RPC generally implies you don't care about response latency.

If the DNS address is not (eventually) re-resolved, then that would be a bug and you should file an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need client-side load balancing as described [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/load-balancing.md). You can watch the endpoints of a service with Kubernetes api. I have created a package for Go programming language and it is on [github](https://github.com/sercand/kuberesolver). Sorry but I didn't write a documentation yet. Basic concept is get service endpoints at beginning than watch service endpoints for changes.

Comment: Please mention what is described from your link as link only answers are frowned upon.  An answer should be able to exist without relying on external sources.