# How to enable grpc reconnection in go?

Tags: go

I was told a grpc client automatically retries to reconnect when server is down.

I tried a [very minimal implementation](https://gist.github.com/audrenbdb/4df8b78aaa43692f891fb4628daf5917) of a server / client where I manually shutdown and then reenable the server.

**Client**:

```
func main() {
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(context.Background(), "localhost:50051", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    exp := time.After(50 * time.Second)
    ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
    for {
        select {
        case <-exp:
            ticker.Stop()
            return
        case <-ticker.C:
            fmt.Printf("Connection status: %s\n", conn.GetState().String())
        }
    }
}
```

**Server**:

```
func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":50051")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    s.Serve(lis)
}
```

When I shutdown the server, the client state is `IDLE`. If I reenable the server, the connection status is not updated as if there was no reconnection attempt.

Is there a native option to enable auto reconnect to a server that was shutdown ?

I've seen two related questions:

- [correct way to perform a reconnect with grpc client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66353603/correct-way-to-perform-a-reconnect-with-grpc-client)
- [grpc clients reconnect inside kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277063/grpc-client-reconnect-inside-kubernetes)

Both implies client should reconnect which is not the case in my minimal example and I'd like to understand why.